# Orientation of iPad app is wrong in the simulator since upgrading to Xcode 4.5.2 - using PhoneGap 1.9

Tags: jquery, ipad, cordova, ios6, xcode4.5

I'm very new to programming and all this. Literally never touched it a short time ago, so my question may be a real beginners' question.

As the title suggests, I upgraded my Xcode yesterday. My supervisor for this Masters project said that I couldn't deploy to my ipad unless I upgraded Xcode, because I need to be able to deploy to iOS 6.0. My Phonegap project was working fine in the simulator until I upgraded Xcode. Now it has rotated 90degrees to the right! The orientation of the simulator is landscape only, as I set it in the iPad deployment info.

Do I need to use some sort of JQuery code to set the orientation? I could really use some help here!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any other way to set the app's orientation but in XCode. In the newest XCode, you need to set the orientation for the iPad and iPhone in different tabs, did you see that? It's also included in my screenshot. My setting for my iPad only app looks like this and it works perfectly:

[image: Screenshot of my XCode settings]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have it set up like that and it worked fine until I updated to xcode 4.5.2. I have played around with all the orientations. Seeing as I'm using Phonegap basically just as a web port (even though the app requires no connection to the internet) it seems that the orientation of the window rather than the device is being misinterpreted in Xcode... I'll keep looking, but thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rotating the simulator (I think Command-Left off the top of my head, though it's also available on the menu)? The orientation of the device is not necessarily connected to the project settings if you don't support all orientations.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I've tried that but to no avail. It seems that the orientation of the window rather than the device is being misinterpreted in Xcode. I might see if Jquery can set the orientation of the window. It works fine in Dreamweaver and then test it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, it turned out that when I updated xcode it seems it wouldn't work properly with phonegap 1.9. I updated to phonegap 2.1 and now it's looking good!